# problems with map network drive batch script and non domain users

Tags: batch-file

I use the following batch script to automatically map a network share for all domain users that logs into a Windows 7 computer.

```
@echo off
net use s: "\\domain.com\path\to\share"
```

I've placed it into the `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` folder so it will run for all users at logon.
If there is a better way, please let me know.

This works fine for the domain users, but local users are asked to enter a username and password.

I want to make my script a bit more elegant. I would like the script to exit/close if a local user logs in. I'm shure I have to write code that does some checking. I just don't know how.

(edited): Registry editing has unfortunately been disabled by the IT department. I also don't have access to the active directory and group policy system.

Comment: Login scripts for domain users should exist in the NETLOGON/LOGONSCRIPTS folder on the domain controller.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, yes, there is a better way. For all users, create a registry entry at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

For only the current user, create a registry entry at:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

You could also place your script in netlogon share if using a domain.

You could just check if %USERDNSDOMAIN% variable contains your domain.
Here's a full group checking logon script you could start with:

https://github.com/deajan/windows_scripts/tree/master/bin/LogonAD

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

you can give an anwser to the "username" prompt (a non-existing username) and redirect output of STDOUT and STDERR to NUL. For Domain members, this answer will be ignored (because there is no question).

```
echo NoAccess|net use s: "\\domain.com\path\to\share" >nul 2>&1
```

Comment: If I want to use an actual username and password how do I do that?

Comment: `net use /?` - if you don't care giving the password in clear text.